# How to tell Typescript compile not to check for path module that he doesn't recognize?

Tags: angular, typescript

[image]

The file is working fine on runtime, means it is found, but .ts don't like when I give a path that not yet there (will be on runtime).

Is there a way to avoid that red line below the path? Telling the compile to avoid checking it?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: if the file is there, try using the `"allowJs": true,` compile option.

Secondly, If the module is known only at runtime you can mock the type with a declaration:

add `declare.d.ts` somewhere in src (or somewhere included in the compilation).

```
declare module "dev/src/app/mycomp.my.component.js"
{
  export class MyComp {} // or whatever. 
}
```